# How to change the printer icon displayed in the Control Panel

Tags: windows-7, printer, icons

Printers are displayed in **Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers** often with a vendor supplied icon.

Is it possible to replace that with a custom icon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Windows Explorer, go to:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Device Metadata\dmrccache
```

And open the appropriate language-specific folder (e.g. for US it is `en-us`). There you will see subfolders corresponding to your installed devices. In each subfolder you'll see a folder named **DeviceInformation**. In that folder is the icon for your device.

You can either replace the icon itself, or you can edit the `DeviceInfo.xml` file and specify a different icon to use.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for this! I was looking for the same thing as the OP. However, I was wondering if you knew why only certain devices were visible in "Device Metadata"; for example, here's my setup: http://screencast.com/t/NTgyOTMxMTM
I only see the icon/entry for the "Dell Laser MFP" in my en-US folder; I don't see anything for the other printers and icons.
I don't suppose you know why, or how I might go about differentiating between them?

Comment: @Pandincus This only works when the device already has a custom icon installed - probably supplied by the manufacturer. If it is using a default icon (a generic icon for all devices of that category), it won't even have a subfolder there, let alone an icon to replace. In this case you need to follow this tutorial to [**add** a custom icon](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/224162-devices-printers-change-device-icons-custom-icons.html).

Answer (score 9):

The location has changed for Windows 8.1.  It's now:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceMetadataCache\dmrccache\en-US
```

Further, you can change the icon(s) to whatever you want using this [Microsoft tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn629490(v=vs.85).aspx).   This [article](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/224162-devices-printers-change-device-icons-custom-icons.html) describes how to use the tool.

Comment: Great answer - I think this should be the new accepted answer once it has some more meat. Als, the "fine article" link is a self-reference... did you mean to link another superuser article here?