# How to fix incorrect icon and name in Windows 7 "Devices and Printers"?

Tags: windows-7, control-panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the printer icon displayed in the Control Panel](https://superuser.com/questions/111036/how-to-change-the-printer-icon-displayed-in-the-control-panel)

My "generic" USB hub is shown as a photo camera (both name and icon) in Windows 7 Devices and Printers (in Control Panel). That specific camera model was connected to that USB hub once. The hub works as expected, and all property pages are available, it just uses a wrong name and icon.

How can I fix this issue and prevent it from happening again in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is some kind of a Windows or driver bug. The [solution for changing the printer icon](https://superuser.com/questions/111036/how-to-change-the-printer-icon-displayed-in-the-control-panel) in Control Panel didn't work as this device's icon and name is **not** stored in `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Device Metadata\dmrccache\en-US`.

I resolved this by doing the following:

1. Went to `device properties`, `driver` tab.
2. Uninstalled the driver.
3. Unplugged the USB hub and plugged it again, so it is re-discovered by Windows.